# Do I need a buffer?

Tags: c++, drawing, buffer, sdl, sfml

I'm here today with a simple "Yes" or "No" question!

I have recently been watching John Purcell's tutorials on C++, 
great tutorials, by the way, and have gotten to the point of creating
a Particle Program in SDL.

However, seeing how SFML is more oriented towards C++, faster, and optimized for more modern day computers, I decided to mimic his tutorial for the Particle Program in SFML. However, he has gotten to a point in his tutorial which I can do without, because SFML provides an easy way to color the whole window using -

```
sf::Color color(sf::Color::White);
//  Many many lines later..
     gameWindow.clear(color);
```

without passing it to the buffer as he did in SDL using -

```
Uint32 *buffer = new Uint32[SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT];
memset(buffer, 0xFF, SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT*sizeof(Uint32));
SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, buffer, SCREEN_WIDTH*sizeof(Uint32));
// More lines of code passing to the Window..
```

So my question is, 
              "Do I need a buffer in SFML?"

Please explain your answer.

Thanks!

Comment: No. SFML abstracts that away from you. The SDL code is just painting over the screen with whatever data is in that buffer, `sf::RenderWindow::clear(...)` takes care of that for you.

Comment: If you had posted that as an answer, Alex, I would have made it the official one. Thanks for the handy info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

You don't need to handle buffering yourself in SFML. The classes already do that for you.